# Intermittent TPMS Light

Tags: tires, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

My TPMS light (not the tire icon, the textual light) has come on as of late, then turned off for a couple of days, then on, and now off again. The tire pressure in all four tires is OK.

As I understand it, this shows that the tire pressure monitoring system is having a problem reading the pressure of the tires, but then, **why would the TPMS light turn off and on, instead of staying on?**

Could the fact that I recently changed the front tires have anything to do with it?

If it matters, I'm driving a 2009 Hyundai Sonata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One other thing you might check is for radio frequency interference to the TPMS from a Bluetooth-equipped device in use in the vehicle.  I personally encountered this situation when using my iPad w/Bluetooth in my 2009 Hyundai Sonata Limited turned on in order to 'wirelessly' transmit audio from podcast app playback to a little Bluetooth receiver which fits in the cigarette lighter power socket (and in turn from there over a short audio cable to my radio's nearby AUX input).  Whenever I would use this setup, more often than not my TPMS indicator lamp on the dash instrument cluster would light up.  Turning off the Bluetooth transmissions from the iPad would "fix" the problem.  Googling on the topic reveals that others have encountered a similar problem.

Comment: This was actually the case: the cheap phone charger I was using was emitting spurious "bluetooth" frequencies. Removing the bad charger solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that you have a wheel sensor going bad in one of your rims. Also, when you say you "The tire pressure on all four tires is OK." ... are they over pressure? The light could come on if there is too much air in a tire just through expansion because it is getting warmer out. I'm not sure if this is viewable through a code reader on the Hyundai, but if it is, it should tell you which tire is actually having the issue, when the light is on, of course.

Also, depending on when exactly you bought the car, this may be covered under warranty. Hyundai has the 60k mile warranty. I'm reaching on this, but it still may be viable under their bumper-to-bumper warranty.

Comment: Tires are around 34, when they should be 32 - so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Then I'll go back to my original thought that one of your tire sensors is going bad.

Comment: Is this something that should be fixed ASAP, or can I wait with it as long as I check the tire pressure frequently?

Comment: As long as you **pay attention** to the tires, it is not an emergency thing. There are no critical systems attached to the sensor. This will just be an annoyance on your dashboard. I don't know for sure, but would bet in most states your car will not pass a safety inspection with the dash light on.

Comment: Same intermittent problem on my 2010 Honda Accord EXL, began sometime after I put more air in the tires for winter. I like running my tires at 35 PSI when warmed-up, traveling on the Interstate. I noticed MY tire pressure increase about 2-3 PSI after warmed up in the Spring and Summer, so I put them at 32 during hot weather. I have not really over-pressured until this year, just relied on Honda to leave them at 35PSI in the winter. Soooooooo, over pressure may be MY issue. Thank you so much for the tip and discussion...very useful.